# Figures overlap even with "constrained_layout=True" in GridSpec

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to plot multiple figures in one plot using GridSpec.
for reference I used the official tutorial but even so I get overlapping figures.
Granted, the figures I display include a confusion matrix, a bar chart and regular plots.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout = True)
    gs0 = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, figure=fig)
    
    #confusion matrix
    gs1 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2,1, subplot_spec=gs0[0])
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0])
    ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions(y_true,y_pred,
                                            labels=self.class_names,
                                            normalize='true', xticks_rotation='vertical', ax=ax)
    
    # bar chart of class frequency
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs1[1])
    keys, counts = np.unique(self.true_labels, return_counts=True)
    ax.bar(keys, counts)

    gs2 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(len(self.class_names)-1,1, subplot_spec=gs0[1])
    for i in range(len(self.class_names)-1):
        y_test = (self.true_labels == i).astype(int)
        y_pred = (self.class_predictions == i).astype(int) * self.class_scores
        tpr, fpr = self._get_fpr_tpr(y_pred, y_test)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(gs2[i])
        ax.plot(fpr,tpr,label='ROC curve', color='g')
        ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], label='Random Classifier (AUC = 0.5)',
                linestyle='--', lw=2, color='r')
        ax.set_xlabel('False Positive Rate')
        ax.set_ylabel('True Positive Rate')
        ax.legend(loc="lower right")
        ax.set_title('ROC Curve for '+self.class_names[i])
    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.plot()
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(self.path_to_save_plot, 'plot.png'))
```

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example. That is with all needed to run it (`from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay` and the like; plus example data such as `y_true`). And without anything unrelated to your question

Comment: You call tight_layout.  That turns off constrained_layout and runs tight_layout, which is less robust.